Apache Ozone Recon version 1.2.0 always shows number of keys as zero
Number of keys api response is giving zero. Even in recon dashboard home page it shows numkeys 17 but in diskspace tab it shows zero. I think this might be bug in 1.2.0 . Does anybody know this bug or configuration setting issue or is it fixed in other versions?
Tried retrieving number of keys not worked

There has been lots of improvements went into Apache Ozone  (which includes Recon related impovements and fixes), please check the latest 1.4.x release of Apache Ozone.
If the issue is still present in the latest release, I can take a look at it.
